# Can't install TWRP LG Optimus G

Tags: adb, custom-roms, twrp, lg

This thread of mine is partly copied from XDA.

I can't get through following issues. Phone's firmware is full vanilla since the very beginning - only updated from Jelly Bean/ICS to 4.4.2 with OTA.
I want to install TWRP Recovery and then try some custom firmwares. I started with making a backup of IMEI/NVRAM by MTK Droid R&T just to be safe.
I can't, IMEI/NVRAM button is greyed out. Log:

```
 --->>> Connect to device <<<---
 --- ERROR  :  --- TotalBytesPerChunk Not Found. Set default Page/Spare=2048/64 !!!
 --- Unknown ROM structure, backup NOT possible!
```

I've looked for solutions. They suggest e.g. searching for MTK app from different source. It doesn't help.
Setting up a root is also a trouble. I tried to use the simpliest, well known method within the reach based on Batch script.
Log:

```
[*] Waiting for device...(Connect your LGOG via USB in Charge Only Mode)
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
[*] Device found.
Beginning Root Process
Now change from Charge Only to MTP
No need to disconnect USB
Press Enter after making the change.
Press any key to continue . . .
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
error: device not found

If uid=0(root), gid=0(root) is displayed
Press Enter to Continue
```

Device is properly connected to adb.

```
(...)\ZV9-ZVB-Universal-Root>adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
LGE9751acf27d9  device
```

Command like `adb reboot bootloader` just restarts the phone. It starts as usually.

Then I tried reinstalling KitKat with OTA hoping that phone will let me do more then. While installation phone got into Download Mode, then it rebooted and - what is strange - **there was no changes at all**. No factory reset occurred.

At the moment I'm helplessly begging/crying for help. Thx for any help/suggestions.